# How can I list and print files in a directory?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying this but it doesn't print anything:

```
Dir -Recurse "C:\temp" | Select Fullname
```

Looks like this command just selects file names. I want to see them in console.

Comment: Can you double check that there are indeed some files and folders in C:\temp and that it is not empty by any chance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [`Get-Childitem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)

```
Dir -Recurse c:\path\ | Get-Childitem
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `Dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. The OP's original code works... at least in PowerShell 3.0. Your code translates to `Get-Childitem -Recurse c:\path\ | Get-Childitem`. See `Get-Alias`. `Alias           dir -> Get-ChildItem  `

Comment: Pretty sure this code will double up output if you have folders in the path since directory will output to the second `Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 4):

## Concerning your code in the question.

Your command should have worked as is. You are, in fact, already calling `Get-ChildItem`. If you check `Get-Alias` you will see what I'm trying to tell you.

```
PS C:\users\Cameron\Downloads> Get-Alias dir

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName                                                                                               
-----------     ----                                               ----------                                                                                               
Alias           dir -> Get-ChildItem
```

You code translates to

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\temp" | Select Fullname
```

Again,  I'm not sure why your code does not generate output since that is perfectly fine on a folder that contains files or directories. Might be an issue with the positional parameter maybe? What is your PowerShell version? ( Use `Get-Host`).

The code you have would send all file paths to console. Did you want that output somewhere else?

## About the accepted answer

Pretty sure this code will double up output if you have folders in the path since directory will output to the second `Get-ChildItem`

```
Dir -Recurse c:\path\ | Get-Childitem
```

Consider the following folder tree

```
C:\TEMP\TEST
│   File1.txt
│   File2.txt
│
└───Folder1
        File3.txt
```

Consider the two command run against that folder tree.

```
PS C:\users\Cameron\Downloads> Dir -Recurse c:\temp\test | Select Fullname

FullName                                                                                                                                                                    
--------                                                                                                                                                                    
C:\temp\test\Folder1                                                                                                                                                        
C:\temp\test\File1.txt                                                                                                                                                      
C:\temp\test\File2.txt                                                                                                                                                      
C:\temp\test\Folder1\File3.txt                                                                                                                                              



PS C:\users\Cameron\Downloads> Dir -Recurse c:\temp\test | Get-Childitem | Select Fullname

FullName                                                                                                                                                                    
--------                                                                                                                                                                    
C:\temp\test\Folder1\File3.txt                                                                                                                                              
C:\temp\test\File1.txt                                                                                                                                                      
C:\temp\test\File2.txt                                                                                                                                                      
C:\temp\test\Folder1\File3.txt
```

The second command shows two files called `File3.txt` when in reality there is only one.

Answer (score 3):

```
get-childitem | format-list > filename.txt
```

This will give you a text file with name, size, last modified, etc.

if you want specific parameters from the item... such as name of the file only the command is

```
get-childitem | format-list name > filename.txt
```

this is give you the same text file, but with just the name of the files listed.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worth mentioning the -force switch which is required to see hidden items.